# Remove brackets with javascript

Tags: javascript, gps

I have a function to get the GPS coordinates once map is clicked, 
 however the result is in brackets () 
I need to remove the brackets

```
function onClickCallback(event){
 var str = event.latLng
 var Gpps = str //.replace("(","");

document.getElementById('latlng').value = Gpps; // resuts provided (in brackets)
```

bellow not giving the gps in any format :(

```
function onClickCallback(event){
    var str = event.latLng
    var Gpps = str.replace("(","");

                        document.getElementById('latlng').value = Gpps; / NO result
```

Comment: There's no `latLng` property in `event`.

Comment: You are calling a string method on event.latLng.  Is that a string?

Comment: @Barmar, based on his code's comments "resuts provided (in brackets)", I'm guessing the `event` in this case does have a latLng property.  He's probably using a map API's callback function, which returns `event.latLng` as an object instead of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback `event.latLng` may be an object instead of a string.

Either of these may get you going:

```
var str = event.latLng.toString().replace(/^\((.+)\)$/,"$1")
```

or

```
var str = event.latLng.toString().slice(1,-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using replace method in javascript you should use regex pattern:

```
.replace(/regex_pattern_here/,'replace_with')
```

So, use like this:

```
str.replace(/()/g,"");//g for global replacement
```

Comment: He wants to remove opening and closing parentheses, so **/\\(\\)/**.

Comment: Assuming you add the escapes, this will only remove the parentheses if they're together, not with numbers between them.